# Python Serial.write doesn't work when in a function

Tags: python, pyserial

I am trying to write to the serial port in the `Start` function to be received by some Arduino code. The problem occurs when the `Calculate` function also contains the `serial.write` command. The function is doing what it is supposed to otherwise but doesn't actually write to the serial port.
(I pretty new at coding for reference)

Here is my python code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import serial
import time

serialPortController = serial.Serial('COM7',38400)
time.sleep(3)

controllerStatus = 0
netTankFlow = 0
currentTankHeight = 50.0

#Calculation Function__________________________________________________________________________________
def Calculate():
    global currentTankHeight
    
    if currentTankHeight == 0.0:
        serialPortController.write(b'10')
    elif currentTankHeight <= 20:
        serialPortController.write(b'11')
    elif currentTankHeight <= 40:
        serialPortController.write(b'12')
    elif currentTankHeight <= 60:
        serialPortController.write(b'13')
    elif currentTankHeight <= 80:
        serialPortController.write(b'14')
    else:
        serialPortController.write(b'15')
        
    tankControllerWindow.update() 
    tankControllerWindow.after(500, Calculate)

#Start & Quit Functions________________________________________________________________________________
def Start():
    global controllerStatus
    startButton.place_forget()
    controllerStatusLabel["text"] = "Controller Status: Active"
    controllerStatusLabel["bg"] = 'lawngreen'
    controllerStatusLabel["fg"] = 'black'
    controllerStatus = 1
    Calculate()
    serialPortController.write(b'41')
            
def Exit():
    quit()

#GUI Window Parameters & Variables_____________________________________________________________________
tankControllerWindow = tk.Tk()
windowWidth = 405
windowHeight = 255
tankControllerWindow.title('Tank Control Interface')
tankControllerWindow.minsize(windowWidth,windowHeight)
tankControllerWindow.configure(bg='whitesmoke')

guiXposition1 = 15
guiXposition4 = guiXposition1 + 300
guiYposition1 = 15


#Start and Exit Buttons________________________________________________________________________________
startButton = tk.Button(text="Start",command=Start)
startButton.place(x=guiXposition1,y=guiYposition1)

controllerStatusLabel = tk.Label(text="Controller Status: Inactive",
                                 bg='darkred',fg='white',width=20,justify='left')
controllerStatusLabel.place(x=guiXposition1+40,y=guiYposition1+2)

exitButton = tk.Button(text="Exit",command=Exit)
exitButton.place(x=guiXposition4+5,y=guiYposition1)

tankControllerWindow.mainloop()
```

And the Arduino Code for testing it

```
byte input;

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(38400);
  
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
}


void loop() {
  
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    input = Serial.parseInt();
  }

  if (input == 41) {
    Command();
  } 

}

void Command(){
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
}
```

Comment: This is not a [mcve]

Comment: This is way too much code for anyone to dig through.

Comment: How do you know it isn't working?

Comment: Every time I delete everything unrelated out it starts working. Give me a minute, I'll see if I can pare it down.

Comment: John, I am using the arduino code I just added.

Comment: Hopefully that is reasonable. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It might also be helpful if you include an minimal example of when it's working vs. when it is not

Comment: So, it's work using Arduino IDE but not working using pyserial?. you should show the output of both codes. Some people bad at guessing.

Comment: Since you aren't including a newline or other non-digit character to terminate the numbers you're sending,  `Serial.parseInt()` can only finish due to a timeout.  The default timeout is 1000 milliseconds - but you're sending a new number every 500 milliseconds, so it never times out.

Comment: Willy: So this is where I don't quite understand what's going on. When it works, the LED designated in the arduino script turns off. That's how I know it's working. I don't actually know what pyserial is.

Comment: Jason: how do I terminate the numbers I am sending independant of a timeout so that ```serial.parseInt()``` only receives one number at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `.write(b'41')` to `.write(b'\n41')` resolved the problem.
Credit to jasonharper. Thanks!